# URL text file not found when deployed to Scraping Hub and spider run

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

## Problem

My spider relies on a `.txt` file that contains the URLs the spider goes to. I have placed that file in the same directory the spider code is located, and in every directory before it (Hail Marry approach); the end result is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/app/__main__.egg/CCSpider1/spiders/cc_1_spider.py", line 41, in start_requests
    for line in fileinput.input({url_file}):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 237, in next
    line = self._readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 339, in _readline
    self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'url_list_20171028Z.txt'
```

### Question

How do I ensure that `url_list_20171028Z.txt` is always found when I run my spider? This URL text file updates every day (a new one is stamped with the next day -- e.x: `url_list_20171029Z.txt`, etc.).

#### Background

Thank you for taking a crack at my issue. I am a new to Python (started learning in June, 2017) and I am taking this scraping project for fun and as a learning expirience. I only started using scrapy recently (October 2017), so apologies for any blatant simplicity passing over my head.

This project has been uploaded to [Scraping Hub](https://scrapinghub.com/) website. This issues is popping up when I try to run my spider from the Scraping Hub dashboard. The deployment of the spider was successful, and I made a `requirements.txt` file to download `Pandas` package used in my spider.

#### My Code

The code below is where the URL text file is called. I reworked the default spider initiated when a new project is started. When I run the spider on my own computer; it operates as desired. Here is the portion of code that calls on `url_list_20171028Z.txt' file to get the URLs to get data from:

```
def start_requests(self):
        s_time = strftime("%Y%m%d" ,gmtime())
        url_file = 'url_list_{0}Z.txt'.format(s_time)
        for line in fileinput.input({url_file}):
            url = str.strip(line)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

**Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out with this issue. If you need me to add anymore information, let me know! Thank you!**

Comment: Did you read this? https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416-deploying-non-code-files

Comment: @Umair Thank you! I had not seen that. I will give it a shot. If you want to put that as an answer, I would be more than happy to send you some love.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the files in the package_data  section of your `setup.py`  file.

For example, if your Scrapy project has the following structure:

```
myproject/
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  resources/
    cities.txt
scrapy.cfg
setup.py
```

You would use the following in your `setup.py`  to include the `cities.txt`  file:

```
setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'myproject': ['resources/*.txt']
    },
    entry_points={
        'scrapy': ['settings = myproject.settings']
    },
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Note that the `zip_safe` flag is set to False , as this may be needed in some cases.

Now you can access the `cities.txt`  file content from `setting.py` like this:

```
import pkgutil

data = pkgutil.get_data("myproject", "resources/cities.txt")
```