# How to make my scrapy read the file which in the same directory?

Tags: python, scrapy

The target file `urls.txt` contains all the url to be downloaded.

```
├─spiders
│  │  stockInfo.py
│  │  urls.txt
│  │  __init__.py
```

`stockInfo.py` is my scrapy file.

```
import scrapy
import os
import re

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stockInfo"
    projectFile = r"d:/toturial/toturial/spiders/urls.txt"
    with open(projectFile,"r") as f:
        urls = f.readlines()
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in urls]

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

I have tested that the above `stockInfo.py` can run successfully in my local pc end  with command:

```
scrapy crawl  stockInfo
```

Now i deploy the project into remote end `scrapy hub` with

```
pip install shub
shub login
API key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
shub deploy 380020
```

It run into  trouble:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd:/toturial/toturial/spiders/urls.txt'
```

How to fix it when to deploy my `scrapy` into the `hub`?
It is useful to rewrite

> projectFile = r"d:/toturial/toturial/spiders/urls.txt"

as

> projectFile = "./urls.txt"

when to run it in my local pc end.

Strangely, it is no use to rewrite

> projectFile = r"d:/toturial/toturial/spiders/urls.txt"

as

> projectFile = "./urls.txt"

when to run it in remote end `scrapy hub`.

Comment: Have a look at [Scrapinghub's documentation](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416-deploying-non-code-files) and  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47018082/4082726).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.add new directory and move `urls.txt` in it.
To add a new directory `resources`,and save `urls.txt` in it.
My new directory tree is as below.

```
tutorial
├─tutorial
│  ├─resources
|     |--urls.txt
│  ├─spiders
|     |--stockInfo.py
```

2.rewrite the setup.py as below.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='tutorial',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'tutorial': ['resources/*.txt']
    },
    entry_points={
        'scrapy': ['settings = tutorial.settings']
    },
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

3.rewrite `stockInfo.py` as below.

```
import scrapy
import os 
import re
import pkgutil
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stockInfo"
    data = pkgutil.get_data("tutorial", "resources/urls.txt")
    data = data.decode()
    start_urls = data.split("\r\n")

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```